# As running a CURL request from Python

Tags: python, api, http, curl

as I can execute the next request from python assuming that " HASH " is a hash associated with a user:

```
$ curl -u HASH:X https://www.example.com/api/ato/users/info/76489246
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm sorry, but I do not completely understand your question. 

If you _have_ to run curl as external command in Python, I recommend using [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call), but note that there are other methods of downloading data over HTTP from inside Python, for example [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).

Comment: The `HASH` you are talking about, is equivalent to username?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi HASH is a string (for ex: t7dr5B1ujphxs043W) associated to username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a good, 3rd party, http lib called [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org). There is an example about authentication on [official doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/).

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```